# Sharing Redux Store Between React Native App, and React Source Inside that App's Webview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a react-native webview component that uses an index.html file for its source like so:

```
source={require("../dist/index.html")}
```

The index.html file itself is a standard react application; it links to a bundle.js file which has been created by webpack and transpiled by babel from a react jsx file.

The overall project could be thought of as two applications; one built from react-native, and the other built from react. They are two parts of a whole.

The problem that I'm having is that I would like them to both share the same redux store.  I've tried having both the react-native and react sides import the same store using the same import statement like so:

```
import {store} from "./store";
```

However, that doesn't work.  I believe it is because the store file is bundled into the react "app" by webpack, so that while react-native and react both point to the same file by name, they are not looking at the same data.

Is there currently a solution to this issue?  I've already successfully used window.postMessage to get the two portions to communicate in the past.  However, I think a redux based approach would be more useful when complicated interactions are required.

Comment: Did you find any way to doing so?

Comment: No, I never did.